# Flutter: Detect state transition between widgets

Tags: flutter

In **Flutter**, is there a way to detect widgets background and foreground state when a widget pushed or popped.

For Example : 
Let's assume there are 2 widgets A and B.

From Widget A, launch Widget B. In this case detect Widget A's state as background and widget B's state as foreground.

Similarly when back pressed from widget B, widget A's state should be detected as foreground.

Comment: `Navigator.push` returns a `Future` that completes when the given route is popped from the stack. Depending on what you want to achieve that might be easier.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data#2-add-a-button-that-launches-the-selection-screen

Answer (score 1):

as an option

1. create RouteObserver
2. assign it to `MaterialApp` `navigatorObservers` property
3. add RouteAware mixing to every page that must be watched
4. override necessary methods like `didPush` `didPopNext` ext
5. PROFIT

this is complete example, I simplified it so RouteAware mixing was added only to FirstPage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>> routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('PRESS ME'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    print('didPush FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print('didPopNext FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    print('didPop FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    print('didPushNext FirstPage');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('BACK'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

also you can create your own Statefull's class `State` and extend from it

another one complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>> routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends RouteAwareState<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('PRESS ME'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends RouteAwareState<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('BACK'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class RouteAwareState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)));
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    print('didPush $widget');
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print('didPopNext $widget');
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    print('didPop $widget');
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    print('didPushNext $widget');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

when you press button and then press Back button it will prints in console

```
I/flutter ( 7188): didPush FirstPage
I/flutter ( 7188): didPushNext FirstPage
I/flutter ( 7188): didPush SecondPage
I/flutter ( 7188): didPopNext FirstPage
I/flutter ( 7188): didPop SecondPage
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work when pushing two routes at once? See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409296/routeraware-didpushnext-is-not-called-when-pushing-two-routes-at-once

Comment: best answer ever ! thanks